# DevFC.exe (Development Fabric) for Windows Azure Crashes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-compute-emulator

Whenever I debug my application (ASP.NET Web Application converted to Web Role), I am able to get to the login page. I go ahead and sign in, debug through that and it seems to work fine, but as soon as it takes me to the landing page after login, DevFC.exe stops working with the error:

> An unhandled exception ('System.Net.Sockets.SocketException') occurred in DevFC.exe [8072].

Now, I've searched for the issue and have seen something about DevFC.exe crashing due to VMWare Workstation that listens on the same port (12000) and HTC Sync that also listens on that port. I have neither of those applications on my machine, so I am lost here. Using TCPView (from Sysinternals), I find no other application using that port.

The one thing I do notice is that [System Process] goes crazy creating connections to localhost:12000 once DevFC.exe gets started.

Anyone have some insight on this?

Comment: I can confirm that VMWare and HTC sync shouldn't be an issue. as it turns out I have both of these and never had an issue with DevFC.exe

Comment: @Slav, I was basing those comments on a thread that I read on MSDN. Here is the link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/7e205afd-4b9a-4387-8e10-99e4b8f27788

Answer (score 2):

This might sound ridiculous but restarting your machine might solve the issue. If that doesn't work, try your project on a different machine. If the project works then there is an issue with your primary machine try uninstalling then reinstalling the Azure SDK. If the devFabric still crashes on the secondary machine then it's something related to your project.

Comment: I've restarted a few times already, but I'll give it another go. As far as trying it on another machine, that will prove to be a little more difficult. I have no access to another Windows Vista/7 machine. I'll update on how it goes.

Comment: Restarted, uninstalled the SDKs, reinstalled from the web, and still no go.

Comment: Is your web role defining a tcp internal endpoint in the service definition (.csdef) file? System.Net.Sockets.SocketException is thrown when the default net.tcp port 808 is used by another process and then you're application is trying to listen to it. Changing the port to something like 888 would probably work for you.
At this point, I suspect that it's something related to your app. You might find this blog post useful http://bit.ly/iATv9V

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the logs created in the DevFC folder here: %localappdata%\dftemp\DevFCLogs (C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\dftmp\DevFCLogs).  This will hopefully shed light on the actual error (which in my case, was a conflict on port 12001.  Ran netstat -ab afterwards and found it was vmware-hostd.exe.  This is a service included with VMWare Workstation 8.  I know you said you don't have that, but you may have some other conflicting software).

See this thread as well for more detail.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/7e205afd-4b9a-4387-8e10-99e4b8f27788

Comment: Travis, thanks for the pointers, but I have gone through the logs (they don't seem to show anything related to an error), and I'm using sysinternals to monitor used ports on my machine. I have zero application attempting to use those ports, except DevFC.